# Copy to clipboard of computer in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Is there a way to create a copy button that copies a field that I want (in this particular instance an address) to the clipboard of the computer, essentially a button that highlights the address and presses control+v when the address is highlighted in visualforce only?

In this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096UHIAY 
The person is able to use javascript in visual force to get what I want but only does it for IE.

In the regular stack exchange, I have seen code for javascript that copies the text onto the clipboard of the keyboard for mozilla, chrome, etc. which are the browsers that the company uses. If there is no component for visualforce that does this function, is my best bet to implement the copy function utilizing javascript with visualforce together?

Comment: Yes this is in essence just a Javascript question. Your implementation shouldn't really be dependent on anything specific to Salesforce. I would post in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think that's unnecessary as there is already a stackexchange question about that. I was wondering if I could solely use visualforce for that function, but it looks like I'll be needing javascript too and that it is not possible.

Comment: No, there is no VF element for this.